# C++ SSL client without certificate with Boost

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, boost-asio, tls1.2

I am trying to develop a simple `SSL` client-server application using `boost::asio`.

I have downloaded, compiled and run the boost example for `ssl` client-server. Nevertheless, in the mentioned example, a certificate must be provided to the client as file in the hard-disk. I want to avoid this.

As far as I know, in the `SSL` protocol, the server can send to the client its certificate. Then, the client uses that certificate during the whole session.

How can I implement the above with the `boost::asio` library?

## EDIT

I want a client that does not need to do this:

```
ctx.load_verify_file("path to certificate.crt");
```

I only want an encrypted connection, I do not need to authenticate anything.

Comment: The edit completely changed the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

A way to use a client without needing to provide it the server's certificate is replace the following code snippet (extracted from the boost ssl example)

```
socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_peer);
socket_.set_verify_callback(
  boost::bind(&client::verify_certificate, this, _1, _2));
```

By this:

```
socket_.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::verify_none);
```

And, in the main method, comment or delete the following line:

```
ctx.load_verify_file("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

It's always the server that sends a certificate. Client certificates are optional, and not often used¹.

So, you want to run a *server* without an external certificate file. In that case, simply read the certificate from another source.

Just replace the lines from server.cpp

```
context_.use_certificate_chain_file("server.pem");
context_.use_private_key_file("server.pem", boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
context_.use_tmp_dh_file("dh2048.pem");
```

With

```
context_.use_certificate_chain(boost::asio::buffer(s_server_pem));
context_.use_private_key(boost::asio::buffer(s_server_pem), boost::asio::ssl::context::pem);
context_.use_tmp_dh(boost::asio::buffer(s_dh2048_pem));
```

The corresponding sample certificate and DH params would be constants like:

```
static unsigned char const s_server_pem[] = {
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x42, 0x45, 0x47, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x43, 0x45, 0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 0x46, 0x49, 0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x2d,
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x49, 0x49, 0x44, 0x41, 0x7a, 0x43, 0x43, 0x41, 0x65, 0x73, 0x43, 0x43, 0x51, 0x44, 0x39, 0x51, 0x63, 0x52, 0x69,
  0x57, 0x6b, 0x30, 0x79, 0x39, 0x54, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x42, 0x67, 0x6b, 0x71, 0x68, 0x6b, 0x69, 0x47, 0x39, 0x77, 0x30, 0x42, 0x41, 0x51, 0x55, 0x46,
  0x41, 0x44, 0x41, 0x37, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x73, 0x77, 0x43, 0x51, 0x59, 0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x47, 0x45, 0x77, 0x4a, 0x42, 0x0a, 0x56, 0x54, 0x45,
  0x4d, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x6f, 0x47, 0x41, 0x31, 0x55, 0x45, 0x43, 0x42, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x54, 0x6c, 0x4e, 0x58, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x38, 0x77, 0x44, 0x51, 0x59,
  0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x48, 0x45, 0x77, 0x5a, 0x54, 0x65, 0x57, 0x52, 0x75, 0x5a, 0x58, 0x6b, 0x78, 0x44, 0x54, 0x41, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e,
  0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x6f, 0x54, 0x42, 0x47, 0x46, 0x7a, 0x61, 0x57, 0x38, 0x77, 0x0a, 0x48, 0x68, 0x63, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x54, 0x55, 0x78, 0x4d, 0x54,
  0x45, 0x34, 0x4d, 0x6a, 0x49, 0x7a, 0x4e, 0x7a, 0x4d, 0x78, 0x57, 0x68, 0x63, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x6a, 0x41, 0x78, 0x4d, 0x54, 0x45, 0x32, 0x4d, 0x6a,
  0x49, 0x7a, 0x4e, 0x7a, 0x4d, 0x78, 0x57, 0x6a, 0x42, 0x4d, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x73, 0x77, 0x43, 0x51, 0x59, 0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x47, 0x45, 0x77,
  0x4a, 0x42, 0x56, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4d, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x6f, 0x47, 0x41, 0x31, 0x55, 0x45, 0x43, 0x42, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x54, 0x6c, 0x4e, 0x58, 0x4d,
  0x51, 0x38, 0x77, 0x44, 0x51, 0x59, 0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x48, 0x45, 0x77, 0x5a, 0x54, 0x65, 0x57, 0x52, 0x75, 0x5a, 0x58, 0x6b, 0x78, 0x44,
  0x54, 0x41, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x6f, 0x54, 0x42, 0x47, 0x46, 0x7a, 0x61, 0x57, 0x38, 0x78, 0x44, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x0a,
  0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x73, 0x54, 0x42, 0x6e, 0x4e, 0x6c, 0x63, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0x6c, 0x63, 0x6a, 0x43, 0x43, 0x41, 0x53, 0x49, 0x77,
  0x44, 0x51, 0x59, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x6f, 0x5a, 0x49, 0x68, 0x76, 0x63, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x51, 0x45, 0x42, 0x42, 0x51, 0x41, 0x44, 0x67, 0x67, 0x45, 0x50,
  0x41, 0x44, 0x43, 0x43, 0x41, 0x51, 0x6f, 0x43, 0x67, 0x67, 0x45, 0x42, 0x41, 0x4c, 0x72, 0x30, 0x0a, 0x2b, 0x4e, 0x58, 0x53, 0x6b, 0x6c, 0x73,
  0x47, 0x4a, 0x52, 0x37, 0x48, 0x59, 0x48, 0x50, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x34, 0x56, 0x35, 0x2b, 0x4b, 0x70, 0x59, 0x72, 0x6d, 0x46, 0x4b, 0x76, 0x61, 0x2f,
  0x4b, 0x37, 0x69, 0x69, 0x71, 0x69, 0x2b, 0x58, 0x79, 0x57, 0x45, 0x6a, 0x47, 0x6e, 0x6a, 0x2b, 0x2f, 0x69, 0x49, 0x6d, 0x4a, 0x57, 0x32, 0x36,
  0x70, 0x68, 0x68, 0x67, 0x39, 0x47, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x4e, 0x0a, 0x4a, 0x4a, 0x78, 0x64, 0x72, 0x50, 0x37, 0x2f, 0x30, 0x4c, 0x77, 0x70, 0x4d, 0x73,
  0x45, 0x43, 0x2f, 0x39, 0x76, 0x30, 0x39, 0x64, 0x4d, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x45, 0x65, 0x77, 0x74, 0x59, 0x68, 0x50, 0x67, 0x44, 0x34, 0x6b, 0x69, 0x55,
  0x48, 0x2f, 0x45, 0x2f, 0x37, 0x39, 0x77, 0x56, 0x6d, 0x61, 0x79, 0x4d, 0x5a, 0x5a, 0x5a, 0x47, 0x72, 0x70, 0x46, 0x39, 0x52, 0x77, 0x2b, 0x77,
  0x57, 0x76, 0x0a, 0x71, 0x35, 0x38, 0x79, 0x33, 0x4c, 0x31, 0x77, 0x4b, 0x67, 0x65, 0x33, 0x71, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x58, 0x36, 0x73, 0x6c, 0x56, 0x44,
  0x64, 0x4e, 0x68, 0x71, 0x55, 0x33, 0x76, 0x42, 0x69, 0x4d, 0x4b, 0x45, 0x4a, 0x66, 0x73, 0x6a, 0x45, 0x34, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x63, 0x45, 0x56, 0x6a,
  0x50, 0x43, 0x6a, 0x56, 0x4a, 0x47, 0x32, 0x35, 0x36, 0x32, 0x65, 0x48, 0x4b, 0x39, 0x46, 0x78, 0x79, 0x6a, 0x51, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x79, 0x6b, 0x79,
  0x48, 0x36, 0x31, 0x6c, 0x51, 0x4b, 0x42, 0x51, 0x4f, 0x69, 0x45, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x50, 0x51, 0x4b, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x37, 0x55, 0x33, 0x36,
  0x79, 0x54, 0x76, 0x73, 0x2b, 0x63, 0x68, 0x57, 0x75, 0x55, 0x66, 0x4b, 0x34, 0x37, 0x42, 0x38, 0x45, 0x43, 0x2b, 0x50, 0x4a, 0x35, 0x4b, 0x63,
  0x4c, 0x45, 0x70, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x34, 0x6c, 0x6a, 0x6c, 0x77, 0x45, 0x0a, 0x77, 0x30, 0x31, 0x48, 0x6e, 0x47, 0x78, 0x77, 0x76, 0x6a, 0x44,
  0x4c, 0x6f, 0x62, 0x4b, 0x6d, 0x32, 0x6a, 0x4c, 0x36, 0x43, 0x57, 0x69, 0x33, 0x61, 0x59, 0x47, 0x57, 0x75, 0x64, 0x79, 0x54, 0x73, 0x4e, 0x41,
  0x64, 0x37, 0x59, 0x43, 0x35, 0x43, 0x37, 0x70, 0x73, 0x6b, 0x74, 0x42, 0x79, 0x70, 0x51, 0x4c, 0x42, 0x63, 0x66, 0x70, 0x37, 0x75, 0x55, 0x72,
  0x72, 0x52, 0x35, 0x42, 0x62, 0x0a, 0x50, 0x45, 0x6a, 0x46, 0x48, 0x4a, 0x55, 0x57, 0x49, 0x6c, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x59, 0x76, 0x6d, 0x32, 0x4f, 0x6a,
  0x4d, 0x43, 0x41, 0x77, 0x45, 0x41, 0x41, 0x54, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x42, 0x67, 0x6b, 0x71, 0x68, 0x6b, 0x69, 0x47, 0x39, 0x77, 0x30, 0x42, 0x41, 0x51,
  0x55, 0x46, 0x41, 0x41, 0x4f, 0x43, 0x41, 0x51, 0x45, 0x41, 0x74, 0x63, 0x65, 0x56, 0x57, 0x36, 0x74, 0x69, 0x78, 0x46, 0x73, 0x42, 0x0a, 0x5a,
  0x52, 0x68, 0x6a, 0x4c, 0x35, 0x61, 0x52, 0x43, 0x63, 0x62, 0x78, 0x32, 0x69, 0x4d, 0x77, 0x45, 0x58, 0x64, 0x35, 0x34, 0x6c, 0x63, 0x50, 0x36,
  0x42, 0x57, 0x65, 0x31, 0x71, 0x4f, 0x63, 0x44, 0x50, 0x48, 0x6f, 0x53, 0x59, 0x49, 0x31, 0x7a, 0x76, 0x76, 0x47, 0x7a, 0x6f, 0x68, 0x62, 0x45,
  0x76, 0x42, 0x66, 0x71, 0x55, 0x76, 0x37, 0x38, 0x53, 0x39, 0x4d, 0x74, 0x7a, 0x61, 0x54, 0x0a, 0x67, 0x4d, 0x65, 0x35, 0x72, 0x49, 0x55, 0x39,
  0x4d, 0x31, 0x5a, 0x4d, 0x30, 0x39, 0x50, 0x79, 0x61, 0x4d, 0x36, 0x5a, 0x75, 0x74, 0x47, 0x70, 0x4b, 0x48, 0x45, 0x38, 0x4c, 0x34, 0x71, 0x63,
  0x4f, 0x73, 0x6c, 0x54, 0x74, 0x34, 0x31, 0x47, 0x51, 0x46, 0x73, 0x53, 0x71, 0x50, 0x46, 0x64, 0x63, 0x62, 0x67, 0x53, 0x56, 0x32, 0x30, 0x4d,
  0x76, 0x42, 0x7a, 0x6a, 0x47, 0x61, 0x79, 0x52, 0x0a, 0x41, 0x49, 0x2f, 0x57, 0x56, 0x30, 0x61, 0x76, 0x57, 0x33, 0x6f, 0x61, 0x73, 0x64, 0x65,
  0x74, 0x4a, 0x50, 0x5a, 0x43, 0x52, 0x37, 0x62, 0x52, 0x62, 0x43, 0x62, 0x4d, 0x62, 0x57, 0x54, 0x67, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x55, 0x66, 0x76, 0x35, 0x46,
  0x32, 0x35, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x63, 0x52, 0x2b, 0x42, 0x68, 0x4e, 0x75, 0x69, 0x6c, 0x66, 0x4c, 0x31, 0x35, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x4c, 0x30, 0x73, 0x34, 0x73,
  0x53, 0x0a, 0x57, 0x62, 0x34, 0x6a, 0x4f, 0x4f, 0x48, 0x68, 0x58, 0x56, 0x39, 0x69, 0x58, 0x65, 0x53, 0x32, 0x64, 0x48, 0x30, 0x73, 0x6e, 0x46,
  0x71, 0x76, 0x34, 0x42, 0x6d, 0x51, 0x39, 0x5a, 0x6f, 0x41, 0x37, 0x7a, 0x62, 0x4d, 0x39, 0x6c, 0x47, 0x33, 0x45, 0x55, 0x35, 0x44, 0x75, 0x78,
  0x48, 0x45, 0x53, 0x59, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x6e, 0x7a, 0x4a, 0x79, 0x45, 0x71, 0x71, 0x59, 0x33, 0x76, 0x57, 0x76, 0x0a, 0x50, 0x46, 0x52, 0x56, 0x69,
  0x43, 0x78, 0x4c, 0x70, 0x35, 0x4c, 0x51, 0x4c, 0x6d, 0x6b, 0x54, 0x51, 0x33, 0x64, 0x67, 0x6c, 0x56, 0x51, 0x41, 0x34, 0x78, 0x36, 0x5a, 0x61,
  0x6f, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x65, 0x77, 0x64, 0x50, 0x74, 0x64, 0x68, 0x6a, 0x6b, 0x4c, 0x55, 0x75, 0x49, 0x71, 0x44, 0x76, 0x51, 0x78, 0x35, 0x2b, 0x6b,
  0x49, 0x61, 0x4f, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x62, 0x53, 0x77, 0x73, 0x2b, 0x63, 0x0a, 0x62, 0x52, 0x45, 0x59, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x47, 0x72, 0x46, 0x77, 0x3d, 0x3d,
  0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x20, 0x43, 0x45, 0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 0x46, 0x49, 0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d,
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x42, 0x45, 0x47, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x20, 0x50, 0x52, 0x49, 0x56, 0x41, 0x54,
  0x45, 0x20, 0x4b, 0x45, 0x59, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x50, 0x72, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x2d, 0x54, 0x79, 0x70, 0x65, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x34, 0x2c,
  0x45, 0x4e, 0x43, 0x52, 0x59, 0x50, 0x54, 0x45, 0x44, 0x0a, 0x44, 0x45, 0x4b, 0x2d, 0x49, 0x6e, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x3a, 0x20, 0x41, 0x45, 0x53, 0x2d,
  0x32, 0x35, 0x36, 0x2d, 0x43, 0x42, 0x43, 0x2c, 0x44, 0x34, 0x35, 0x39, 0x36, 0x37, 0x36, 0x33, 0x34, 0x37, 0x44, 0x33, 0x38, 0x39, 0x45, 0x39,
  0x31, 0x33, 0x35, 0x34, 0x39, 0x36, 0x44, 0x38, 0x41, 0x41, 0x46, 0x41, 0x37, 0x39, 0x35, 0x33, 0x0a, 0x0a, 0x77, 0x62, 0x72, 0x6a, 0x78, 0x72,
  0x39, 0x4e, 0x48, 0x75, 0x72, 0x38, 0x6b, 0x67, 0x78, 0x44, 0x73, 0x67, 0x58, 0x4f, 0x59, 0x39, 0x71, 0x46, 0x47, 0x4b, 0x70, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x49,
  0x51, 0x4c, 0x78, 0x6b, 0x75, 0x61, 0x68, 0x55, 0x72, 0x44, 0x44, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x2b, 0x73, 0x2f, 0x6c, 0x37, 0x75, 0x67, 0x73, 0x4c, 0x57, 0x4f,
  0x50, 0x73, 0x4f, 0x58, 0x62, 0x6a, 0x4e, 0x4c, 0x2f, 0x37, 0x0a, 0x51, 0x59, 0x55, 0x42, 0x41, 0x78, 0x38, 0x35, 0x48, 0x4b, 0x6d, 0x39, 0x44,
  0x38, 0x42, 0x51, 0x35, 0x67, 0x37, 0x38, 0x59, 0x38, 0x32, 0x71, 0x66, 0x41, 0x72, 0x61, 0x70, 0x33, 0x2f, 0x33, 0x49, 0x49, 0x75, 0x79, 0x73,
  0x44, 0x66, 0x51, 0x44, 0x68, 0x34, 0x66, 0x51, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x68, 0x56, 0x74, 0x6d, 0x47, 0x54, 0x46, 0x69, 0x43, 0x4f, 0x76, 0x75, 0x64, 0x6c,
  0x47, 0x45, 0x70, 0x0a, 0x6c, 0x71, 0x31, 0x6e, 0x69, 0x51, 0x52, 0x4c, 0x54, 0x68, 0x6c, 0x78, 0x65, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x46, 0x70, 0x68, 0x48, 0x38,
  0x4b, 0x4b, 0x69, 0x4f, 0x54, 0x4f, 0x39, 0x61, 0x2f, 0x64, 0x38, 0x74, 0x64, 0x4c, 0x37, 0x7a, 0x52, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x46, 0x77, 0x6e, 0x56, 0x6e,
  0x68, 0x4b, 0x34, 0x30, 0x31, 0x34, 0x6d, 0x67, 0x56, 0x6d, 0x67, 0x63, 0x53, 0x65, 0x66, 0x41, 0x31, 0x41, 0x46, 0x35, 0x0a, 0x52, 0x62, 0x4a,
  0x41, 0x65, 0x4d, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x55, 0x4b, 0x64, 0x64, 0x47, 0x36, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x51, 0x4b, 0x30, 0x30, 0x70, 0x74, 0x67, 0x38, 0x34, 0x43, 0x44,
  0x58, 0x69, 0x4d, 0x57, 0x51, 0x58, 0x46, 0x42, 0x47, 0x47, 0x6d, 0x51, 0x31, 0x61, 0x76, 0x32, 0x6c, 0x79, 0x46, 0x7a, 0x43, 0x2b, 0x78, 0x4c,
  0x50, 0x2b, 0x71, 0x44, 0x71, 0x5a, 0x41, 0x59, 0x54, 0x4d, 0x39, 0x6c, 0x5a, 0x0a, 0x4e, 0x46, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x32, 0x6f, 0x45, 0x5a, 0x50, 0x31,
  0x6f, 0x7a, 0x66, 0x4f, 0x56, 0x4e, 0x53, 0x62, 0x58, 0x54, 0x61, 0x6e, 0x4a, 0x67, 0x5a, 0x30, 0x44, 0x53, 0x53, 0x6d, 0x68, 0x47, 0x45, 0x31,
  0x50, 0x63, 0x56, 0x72, 0x48, 0x53, 0x65, 0x45, 0x2f, 0x76, 0x2b, 0x6b, 0x31, 0x6b, 0x50, 0x68, 0x33, 0x6f, 0x56, 0x4b, 0x69, 0x39, 0x47, 0x56,
  0x35, 0x31, 0x6b, 0x49, 0x44, 0x43, 0x0a, 0x5a, 0x64, 0x39, 0x66, 0x2f, 0x58, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x75, 0x44, 0x4f, 0x7a, 0x79, 0x31, 0x59, 0x62, 0x6e,
  0x36, 0x67, 0x52, 0x79, 0x34, 0x6e, 0x7a, 0x4e, 0x70, 0x7a, 0x63, 0x77, 0x6a, 0x53, 0x43, 0x49, 0x48, 0x45, 0x64, 0x53, 0x44, 0x35, 0x6e, 0x78,
  0x55, 0x35, 0x4a, 0x66, 0x48, 0x66, 0x51, 0x33, 0x4f, 0x74, 0x6e, 0x73, 0x45, 0x61, 0x62, 0x37, 0x71, 0x66, 0x39, 0x38, 0x39, 0x69, 0x50, 0x0a,
  0x73, 0x32, 0x4c, 0x62, 0x43, 0x53, 0x70, 0x35, 0x75, 0x47, 0x54, 0x4d, 0x76, 0x66, 0x65, 0x73, 0x4d, 0x49, 0x6b, 0x69, 0x78, 0x49, 0x5a, 0x41,
  0x51, 0x70, 0x32, 0x46, 0x65, 0x61, 0x68, 0x5a, 0x54, 0x41, 0x67, 0x55, 0x32, 0x56, 0x78, 0x2b, 0x77, 0x69, 0x35, 0x4b, 0x6b, 0x73, 0x36, 0x38,
  0x72, 0x4f, 0x71, 0x65, 0x79, 0x77, 0x45, 0x66, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x43, 0x4c, 0x2f, 0x55, 0x6d, 0x35, 0x0a, 0x37, 0x58, 0x5a, 0x75, 0x38, 0x67, 0x44,
  0x73, 0x34, 0x4d, 0x67, 0x52, 0x52, 0x57, 0x6e, 0x78, 0x4b, 0x31, 0x42, 0x62, 0x4a, 0x44, 0x50, 0x69, 0x66, 0x49, 0x43, 0x4c, 0x76, 0x53, 0x4a,
  0x5a, 0x76, 0x67, 0x42, 0x39, 0x46, 0x4b, 0x58, 0x2f, 0x68, 0x6b, 0x34, 0x46, 0x48, 0x46, 0x46, 0x2b, 0x4d, 0x74, 0x63, 0x72, 0x6b, 0x61, 0x6c,
  0x65, 0x68, 0x43, 0x75, 0x4c, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x44, 0x56, 0x0a, 0x33, 0x72, 0x66, 0x48, 0x4e, 0x76, 0x52, 0x53, 0x62, 0x67, 0x37, 0x4a, 0x39, 0x37,
  0x58, 0x51, 0x33, 0x51, 0x43, 0x2b, 0x6b, 0x39, 0x5a, 0x44, 0x61, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x79, 0x36, 0x6e, 0x2b, 0x4c, 0x68, 0x61, 0x56, 0x76, 0x37,
  0x42, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x52, 0x42, 0x6e, 0x42, 0x42, 0x74, 0x5a, 0x35, 0x45, 0x67, 0x33, 0x44, 0x6d, 0x50, 0x67, 0x36, 0x66, 0x6c, 0x71, 0x61, 0x48,
  0x41, 0x55, 0x0a, 0x59, 0x2f, 0x38, 0x64, 0x38, 0x32, 0x77, 0x62, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x43, 0x6d, 0x62, 0x76, 0x52, 0x33, 0x42, 0x31, 0x2f, 0x45, 0x62,
  0x67, 0x73, 0x38, 0x34, 0x44, 0x50, 0x4a, 0x2b, 0x75, 0x5a, 0x6e, 0x59, 0x39, 0x4d, 0x35, 0x49, 0x77, 0x78, 0x31, 0x39, 0x6f, 0x71, 0x6c, 0x56,
  0x53, 0x52, 0x32, 0x74, 0x73, 0x2f, 0x54, 0x78, 0x36, 0x31, 0x39, 0x4c, 0x47, 0x41, 0x6d, 0x2b, 0x42, 0x69, 0x51, 0x0a, 0x37, 0x59, 0x44, 0x6f,
  0x43, 0x34, 0x43, 0x46, 0x6d, 0x70, 0x41, 0x41, 0x38, 0x55, 0x77, 0x30, 0x78, 0x6e, 0x55, 0x62, 0x4e, 0x67, 0x78, 0x39, 0x34, 0x4e, 0x64, 0x4e,
  0x6d, 0x6c, 0x6e, 0x4c, 0x65, 0x4c, 0x74, 0x53, 0x35, 0x30, 0x62, 0x30, 0x58, 0x6c, 0x57, 0x70, 0x48, 0x4b, 0x62, 0x56, 0x7a, 0x6d, 0x56, 0x62,
  0x4e, 0x59, 0x45, 0x6a, 0x59, 0x36, 0x4e, 0x48, 0x4d, 0x6c, 0x4c, 0x74, 0x0a, 0x61, 0x71, 0x78, 0x57, 0x48, 0x54, 0x59, 0x54, 0x61, 0x37, 0x67,
  0x2f, 0x63, 0x31, 0x62, 0x67, 0x32, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x78, 0x46, 0x31, 0x4c, 0x62, 0x66, 0x75, 0x35, 0x56, 0x53, 0x54, 0x52, 0x4f, 0x47, 0x42, 0x55,
  0x75, 0x65, 0x72, 0x31, 0x63, 0x33, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x56, 0x75, 0x79, 0x42, 0x72, 0x6a, 0x63, 0x58, 0x39, 0x32, 0x4a, 0x70, 0x34, 0x42, 0x4a, 0x48,
  0x37, 0x38, 0x71, 0x4f, 0x70, 0x0a, 0x4e, 0x36, 0x6c, 0x59, 0x36, 0x4d, 0x6e, 0x48, 0x34, 0x48, 0x59, 0x52, 0x58, 0x48, 0x6a, 0x7a, 0x6c, 0x74,
  0x2f, 0x53, 0x30, 0x5a, 0x7a, 0x4f, 0x30, 0x66, 0x61, 0x50, 0x50, 0x65, 0x31, 0x38, 0x51, 0x38, 0x53, 0x57, 0x76, 0x6e, 0x44, 0x56, 0x75, 0x45,
  0x33, 0x66, 0x59, 0x7a, 0x7a, 0x4c, 0x37, 0x37, 0x32, 0x42, 0x35, 0x36, 0x64, 0x32, 0x74, 0x38, 0x65, 0x6f, 0x64, 0x63, 0x2b, 0x2f, 0x0a, 0x74,
  0x36, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x71, 0x4a, 0x36, 0x30, 0x65, 0x58, 0x64, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x67, 0x59, 0x4f, 0x61, 0x50, 0x52, 0x4c, 0x52, 0x55, 0x6f, 0x76, 0x4e,
  0x32, 0x78, 0x54, 0x32, 0x55, 0x55, 0x72, 0x30, 0x2b, 0x62, 0x69, 0x75, 0x67, 0x75, 0x48, 0x79, 0x71, 0x66, 0x61, 0x56, 0x66, 0x63, 0x45, 0x55,
  0x2f, 0x61, 0x64, 0x77, 0x2b, 0x62, 0x39, 0x6f, 0x55, 0x56, 0x45, 0x2b, 0x35, 0x4e, 0x77, 0x0a, 0x6e, 0x5a, 0x48, 0x49, 0x35, 0x71, 0x68, 0x50,
  0x6e, 0x68, 0x4c, 0x78, 0x43, 0x68, 0x79, 0x5a, 0x71, 0x62, 0x42, 0x6c, 0x36, 0x38, 0x7a, 0x4d, 0x55, 0x79, 0x4b, 0x6c, 0x66, 0x66, 0x66, 0x34,
  0x4f, 0x79, 0x4c, 0x76, 0x52, 0x47, 0x70, 0x66, 0x63, 0x48, 0x77, 0x42, 0x77, 0x36, 0x44, 0x54, 0x47, 0x6a, 0x64, 0x75, 0x42, 0x2b, 0x44, 0x44,
  0x73, 0x71, 0x71, 0x6b, 0x63, 0x49, 0x42, 0x39, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x56, 0x4c, 0x36, 0x6e, 0x70, 0x73, 0x37, 0x5a, 0x56, 0x43, 0x77, 0x4d, 0x50, 0x49,
  0x31, 0x38, 0x73, 0x69, 0x55, 0x64, 0x36, 0x63, 0x74, 0x74, 0x45, 0x4f, 0x66, 0x36, 0x5a, 0x58, 0x72, 0x56, 0x71, 0x48, 0x67, 0x39, 0x77, 0x66,
  0x44, 0x76, 0x4a, 0x4f, 0x6c, 0x68, 0x32, 0x4e, 0x4e, 0x4b, 0x4e, 0x4c, 0x78, 0x53, 0x41, 0x46, 0x75, 0x62, 0x48, 0x63, 0x39, 0x30, 0x4a, 0x6c,
  0x6a, 0x0a, 0x4b, 0x65, 0x6a, 0x72, 0x57, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x58, 0x6f, 0x32, 0x77, 0x36, 0x59, 0x6b, 0x53, 0x55, 0x65, 0x54, 0x56, 0x34, 0x74, 0x34,
  0x63, 0x57, 0x75, 0x37, 0x55, 0x38, 0x72, 0x58, 0x49, 0x6b, 0x54, 0x4a, 0x58, 0x44, 0x6c, 0x31, 0x53, 0x36, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x38, 0x44, 0x57, 0x71,
  0x4e, 0x44, 0x6f, 0x35, 0x4b, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x4a, 0x32, 0x53, 0x4b, 0x35, 0x4e, 0x6c, 0x53, 0x4f, 0x4a, 0x37, 0x0a, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x45, 0x43, 0x6e,
  0x33, 0x39, 0x30, 0x6f, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x65, 0x4a, 0x4f, 0x78, 0x78, 0x79, 0x74, 0x50, 0x56, 0x51, 0x4f, 0x32, 0x78, 0x70, 0x70, 0x58, 0x51, 0x5a,
  0x5a, 0x53, 0x36, 0x35, 0x52, 0x48, 0x72, 0x76, 0x68, 0x42, 0x2b, 0x73, 0x73, 0x35, 0x78, 0x55, 0x6b, 0x6e, 0x6c, 0x79, 0x39, 0x71, 0x2b, 0x49,
  0x43, 0x79, 0x74, 0x36, 0x78, 0x54, 0x52, 0x39, 0x6e, 0x71, 0x41, 0x0a, 0x50, 0x4b, 0x6b, 0x65, 0x53, 0x45, 0x36, 0x71, 0x56, 0x59, 0x30, 0x4a,
  0x34, 0x4a, 0x67, 0x46, 0x58, 0x70, 0x6b, 0x67, 0x51, 0x78, 0x67, 0x77, 0x4d, 0x6e, 0x6a, 0x53, 0x45, 0x44, 0x33, 0x4c, 0x4b, 0x72, 0x33, 0x6a,
  0x6c, 0x7a, 0x32, 0x38, 0x70, 0x72, 0x35, 0x63, 0x43, 0x36, 0x74, 0x73, 0x63, 0x35, 0x53, 0x53, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6b, 0x48, 0x6a, 0x54, 0x32, 0x66,
  0x63, 0x53, 0x72, 0x58, 0x0a, 0x75, 0x63, 0x63, 0x61, 0x56, 0x61, 0x68, 0x61, 0x4a, 0x52, 0x69, 0x67, 0x66, 0x2b, 0x71, 0x2b, 0x34, 0x58, 0x7a,
  0x6d, 0x4a, 0x74, 0x64, 0x77, 0x62, 0x5a, 0x55, 0x2b, 0x59, 0x57, 0x47, 0x5a, 0x52, 0x56, 0x4d, 0x6c, 0x51, 0x4c, 0x41, 0x35, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x50,
  0x48, 0x51, 0x48, 0x44, 0x59, 0x6b, 0x50, 0x70, 0x4f, 0x65, 0x59, 0x55, 0x34, 0x57, 0x52, 0x65, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x38, 0x53, 0x34, 0x0a, 0x54, 0x5a,
  0x52, 0x6b, 0x50, 0x48, 0x61, 0x78, 0x4f, 0x5a, 0x32, 0x6c, 0x4b, 0x51, 0x77, 0x4a, 0x42, 0x39, 0x33, 0x56, 0x38, 0x56, 0x62, 0x74, 0x32, 0x4d,
  0x76, 0x77, 0x52, 0x79, 0x33, 0x39, 0x32, 0x34, 0x35, 0x32, 0x61, 0x33, 0x33, 0x53, 0x34, 0x54, 0x63, 0x51, 0x4c, 0x61, 0x57, 0x7a, 0x6f, 0x4f,
  0x6c, 0x6a, 0x58, 0x6a, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6a, 0x72, 0x70, 0x32, 0x72, 0x76, 0x52, 0x7a, 0x0a, 0x70, 0x72, 0x42, 0x61, 0x4e, 0x65, 0x38, 0x4c, 0x6e,
  0x4f, 0x34, 0x56, 0x38, 0x4f, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x76, 0x2b, 0x48, 0x2b, 0x45, 0x30, 0x55, 0x57, 0x69, 0x57, 0x46, 0x44, 0x75, 0x49, 0x2b, 0x48, 0x42,
  0x79, 0x34, 0x58, 0x34, 0x4f, 0x39, 0x70, 0x6c, 0x73, 0x62, 0x77, 0x2f, 0x67, 0x6b, 0x36, 0x34, 0x50, 0x68, 0x6c, 0x39, 0x71, 0x4c, 0x69, 0x42,
  0x77, 0x61, 0x58, 0x2f, 0x41, 0x49, 0x52, 0x0a, 0x36, 0x36, 0x46, 0x58, 0x76, 0x43, 0x2f, 0x63, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x42, 0x6f, 0x39, 0x6f, 0x53, 0x74,
  0x32, 0x6a, 0x65, 0x6b, 0x63, 0x4d, 0x74, 0x4a, 0x6f, 0x66, 0x59, 0x72, 0x38, 0x47, 0x72, 0x32, 0x62, 0x73, 0x4a, 0x6c, 0x74, 0x35, 0x5a, 0x58,
  0x2b, 0x47, 0x45, 0x4f, 0x78, 0x7a, 0x34, 0x6a, 0x4d, 0x76, 0x37, 0x78, 0x76, 0x7a, 0x35, 0x2f, 0x4c, 0x33, 0x57, 0x37, 0x6a, 0x56, 0x61, 0x76,
  0x0a, 0x70, 0x48, 0x47, 0x49, 0x76, 0x34, 0x78, 0x66, 0x4e, 0x39, 0x46, 0x72, 0x58, 0x7a, 0x4c, 0x34, 0x37, 0x4f, 0x37, 0x55, 0x75, 0x55, 0x46,
  0x39, 0x78, 0x5a, 0x67, 0x34, 0x52, 0x70, 0x2f, 0x66, 0x78, 0x77, 0x70, 0x67, 0x45, 0x44, 0x4e, 0x5a, 0x6d, 0x58, 0x2f, 0x33, 0x44, 0x6e, 0x50,
  0x30, 0x65, 0x77, 0x5a, 0x51, 0x55, 0x63, 0x67, 0x55, 0x58, 0x30, 0x70, 0x64, 0x71, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x51, 0x0a, 0x59, 0x56, 0x71, 0x4a, 0x58, 0x63,
  0x52, 0x46, 0x37, 0x4b, 0x71, 0x47, 0x32, 0x4e, 0x53, 0x51, 0x46, 0x75, 0x77, 0x50, 0x45, 0x53, 0x5a, 0x51, 0x6e, 0x78, 0x55, 0x30, 0x57, 0x7a,
  0x53, 0x67, 0x52, 0x79, 0x55, 0x61, 0x65, 0x37, 0x78, 0x67, 0x31, 0x57, 0x4b, 0x66, 0x53, 0x75, 0x4e, 0x38, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x41, 0x7a, 0x4b, 0x68,
  0x4f, 0x67, 0x65, 0x71, 0x6c, 0x44, 0x32, 0x49, 0x41, 0x6f, 0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x20, 0x52, 0x53, 0x41, 0x20,
  0x50, 0x52, 0x49, 0x56, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x20, 0x4b, 0x45, 0x59, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x42, 0x45,
  0x47, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x43, 0x45, 0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 0x46, 0x49, 0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x49, 0x49,
  0x44, 0x6c, 0x7a, 0x43, 0x43, 0x41, 0x6e, 0x2b, 0x67, 0x41, 0x77, 0x49, 0x42, 0x41, 0x67, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x4a, 0x59, 0x55, 0x33, 0x55,
  0x36, 0x41, 0x30, 0x49, 0x52, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x30, 0x47, 0x43, 0x53, 0x71, 0x47, 0x53, 0x49, 0x62, 0x33, 0x44, 0x51, 0x45, 0x42, 0x42, 0x51, 0x55,
  0x41, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x73, 0x78, 0x43, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4a, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x0a, 0x42, 0x41, 0x59, 0x54, 0x41, 0x6b, 0x46, 0x56, 0x4d, 0x51,
  0x77, 0x77, 0x43, 0x67, 0x59, 0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x77, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x55, 0x31, 0x63, 0x78, 0x44, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x42, 0x67,
  0x4e, 0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x63, 0x54, 0x42, 0x6c, 0x4e, 0x35, 0x5a, 0x47, 0x35, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x73, 0x47, 0x41, 0x31,
  0x55, 0x45, 0x43, 0x68, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x0a, 0x59, 0x58, 0x4e, 0x70, 0x62, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x65, 0x46, 0x77, 0x30, 0x78, 0x4e, 0x54, 0x45, 0x78, 0x4d,
  0x54, 0x67, 0x79, 0x4d, 0x6a, 0x4d, 0x7a, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x68, 0x61, 0x46, 0x77, 0x30, 0x79, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x45, 0x78, 0x4d, 0x54, 0x59, 0x79, 0x4d,
  0x6a, 0x4d, 0x7a, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x68, 0x61, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x73, 0x78, 0x43, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4a, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x59, 0x54, 0x0a,
  0x41, 0x6b, 0x46, 0x56, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x77, 0x77, 0x43, 0x67, 0x59, 0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x77, 0x4e, 0x4f, 0x55, 0x31, 0x63, 0x78,
  0x44, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x63, 0x54, 0x42, 0x6c, 0x4e, 0x35, 0x5a, 0x47, 0x35, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4e,
  0x4d, 0x41, 0x73, 0x47, 0x41, 0x31, 0x55, 0x45, 0x43, 0x68, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x59, 0x58, 0x4e, 0x70, 0x0a, 0x62, 0x7a, 0x43, 0x43, 0x41, 0x53, 0x49,
  0x77, 0x44, 0x51, 0x59, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x6f, 0x5a, 0x49, 0x68, 0x76, 0x63, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x51, 0x45, 0x42, 0x42, 0x51, 0x41, 0x44, 0x67, 0x67, 0x45,
  0x50, 0x41, 0x44, 0x43, 0x43, 0x41, 0x51, 0x6f, 0x43, 0x67, 0x67, 0x45, 0x42, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x63, 0x52, 0x4a, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x48, 0x64, 0x56, 0x4d,
  0x64, 0x4c, 0x55, 0x4a, 0x2f, 0x70, 0x79, 0x70, 0x59, 0x0a, 0x51, 0x56, 0x53, 0x54, 0x43, 0x30, 0x74, 0x33, 0x49, 0x49, 0x67, 0x6a, 0x77, 0x6a,
  0x61, 0x7a, 0x72, 0x4b, 0x33, 0x6b, 0x41, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x49, 0x4d, 0x76, 0x7a, 0x50, 0x6d, 0x44, 0x46, 0x78, 0x45, 0x58, 0x57, 0x63, 0x44, 0x78,
  0x2b, 0x6e, 0x79, 0x7a, 0x38, 0x6b, 0x51, 0x2f, 0x45, 0x33, 0x38, 0x49, 0x72, 0x2f, 0x65, 0x66, 0x32, 0x42, 0x43, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x63, 0x69, 0x35,
  0x68, 0x75, 0x0a, 0x77, 0x6b, 0x66, 0x4d, 0x53, 0x75, 0x4d, 0x6f, 0x57, 0x39, 0x6c, 0x32, 0x4e, 0x34, 0x68, 0x78, 0x33, 0x51, 0x43, 0x63, 0x46,
  0x34, 0x36, 0x74, 0x54, 0x44, 0x45, 0x5a, 0x7a, 0x74, 0x46, 0x78, 0x57, 0x41, 0x48, 0x37, 0x51, 0x62, 0x45, 0x32, 0x77, 0x59, 0x4d, 0x6c, 0x4d,
  0x67, 0x4b, 0x5a, 0x53, 0x78, 0x57, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x4e, 0x66, 0x71, 0x30, 0x59, 0x6a, 0x78, 0x45, 0x45, 0x58, 0x62, 0x0a, 0x51, 0x4d, 0x30, 0x6c,
  0x47, 0x50, 0x4c, 0x46, 0x68, 0x37, 0x58, 0x6f, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0x32, 0x39, 0x48, 0x30, 0x46, 0x33, 0x4c, 0x4b, 0x61, 0x61, 0x51, 0x56, 0x39, 0x75,
  0x2f, 0x76, 0x6f, 0x70, 0x33, 0x48, 0x73, 0x30, 0x68, 0x31, 0x32, 0x48, 0x65, 0x57, 0x6c, 0x59, 0x34, 0x50, 0x69, 0x4c, 0x70, 0x37, 0x51, 0x51,
  0x54, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x71, 0x62, 0x57, 0x63, 0x58, 0x79, 0x63, 0x41, 0x30, 0x0a, 0x4e, 0x5a, 0x2f, 0x66, 0x79, 0x69, 0x73, 0x6d, 0x69, 0x72, 0x65,
  0x79, 0x45, 0x76, 0x50, 0x41, 0x67, 0x6f, 0x36, 0x4c, 0x38, 0x69, 0x58, 0x75, 0x41, 0x69, 0x37, 0x67, 0x30, 0x54, 0x56, 0x4b, 0x56, 0x4e, 0x6c,
  0x72, 0x74, 0x69, 0x63, 0x47, 0x47, 0x6a, 0x4d, 0x63, 0x4d, 0x71, 0x36, 0x49, 0x4d, 0x76, 0x78, 0x7a, 0x45, 0x70, 0x53, 0x4d, 0x6b, 0x75, 0x4d,
  0x51, 0x35, 0x72, 0x57, 0x6a, 0x0a, 0x70, 0x5a, 0x6a, 0x57, 0x4f, 0x6f, 0x42, 0x6a, 0x53, 0x59, 0x42, 0x75, 0x58, 0x64, 0x62, 0x6c, 0x63, 0x42,
  0x52, 0x76, 0x58, 0x68, 0x4f, 0x72, 0x32, 0x57, 0x73, 0x38, 0x6a, 0x4a, 0x4c, 0x4d, 0x5a, 0x66, 0x65, 0x68, 0x4b, 0x71, 0x39, 0x71, 0x31, 0x72,
  0x65, 0x51, 0x66, 0x6f, 0x47, 0x56, 0x36, 0x78, 0x4d, 0x6e, 0x62, 0x77, 0x6d, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x53, 0x58, 0x62, 0x57, 0x52, 0x57, 0x54, 0x0a, 0x30,
  0x76, 0x6b, 0x43, 0x41, 0x77, 0x45, 0x41, 0x41, 0x61, 0x4f, 0x42, 0x6e, 0x54, 0x43, 0x42, 0x6d, 0x6a, 0x41, 0x64, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x48,
  0x51, 0x34, 0x45, 0x46, 0x67, 0x51, 0x55, 0x4b, 0x2f, 0x5a, 0x76, 0x2f, 0x41, 0x56, 0x74, 0x66, 0x49, 0x65, 0x75, 0x63, 0x4a, 0x77, 0x38, 0x56,
  0x45, 0x74, 0x75, 0x78, 0x31, 0x64, 0x68, 0x49, 0x31, 0x59, 0x77, 0x61, 0x77, 0x59, 0x44, 0x0a, 0x56, 0x52, 0x30, 0x6a, 0x42, 0x47, 0x51, 0x77,
  0x59, 0x6f, 0x41, 0x55, 0x4b, 0x2f, 0x5a, 0x76, 0x2f, 0x41, 0x56, 0x74, 0x66, 0x49, 0x65, 0x75, 0x63, 0x4a, 0x77, 0x38, 0x56, 0x45, 0x74, 0x75,
  0x78, 0x31, 0x64, 0x68, 0x49, 0x31, 0x61, 0x68, 0x50, 0x36, 0x51, 0x39, 0x4d, 0x44, 0x73, 0x78, 0x43, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4a, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56,
  0x42, 0x41, 0x59, 0x54, 0x41, 0x6b, 0x46, 0x56, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x51, 0x77, 0x77, 0x43, 0x67, 0x59, 0x44, 0x56, 0x51, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x77, 0x4e,
  0x4f, 0x55, 0x31, 0x63, 0x78, 0x44, 0x7a, 0x41, 0x4e, 0x42, 0x67, 0x4e, 0x56, 0x42, 0x41, 0x63, 0x54, 0x42, 0x6c, 0x4e, 0x35, 0x5a, 0x47, 0x35,
  0x6c, 0x65, 0x54, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x73, 0x47, 0x41, 0x31, 0x55, 0x45, 0x43, 0x68, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x59, 0x58, 0x4e, 0x70, 0x62, 0x34, 0x49,
  0x4a, 0x0a, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x4a, 0x59, 0x55, 0x33, 0x55, 0x36, 0x41, 0x30, 0x49, 0x52, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x77, 0x47, 0x41, 0x31, 0x55, 0x64, 0x45, 0x77,
  0x51, 0x46, 0x4d, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x42, 0x41, 0x66, 0x38, 0x77, 0x44, 0x51, 0x59, 0x4a, 0x4b, 0x6f, 0x5a, 0x49, 0x68, 0x76, 0x63, 0x4e, 0x41, 0x51,
  0x45, 0x46, 0x42, 0x51, 0x41, 0x44, 0x67, 0x67, 0x45, 0x42, 0x41, 0x42, 0x4c, 0x59, 0x58, 0x69, 0x6d, 0x71, 0x0a, 0x76, 0x2f, 0x48, 0x4c, 0x79,
  0x49, 0x4a, 0x69, 0x37, 0x58, 0x6e, 0x38, 0x41, 0x4a, 0x55, 0x73, 0x49, 0x43, 0x6a, 0x38, 0x4c, 0x4b, 0x46, 0x2f, 0x4a, 0x32, 0x34, 0x6e, 0x77,
  0x77, 0x69, 0x46, 0x2b, 0x69, 0x62, 0x66, 0x37, 0x55, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0x43, 0x68, 0x4a, 0x55, 0x52, 0x73, 0x34, 0x6e, 0x4e, 0x37, 0x38, 0x62, 0x6f,
  0x64, 0x2f, 0x6c, 0x70, 0x44, 0x56, 0x50, 0x54, 0x45, 0x56, 0x6c, 0x0a, 0x67, 0x54, 0x42, 0x64, 0x56, 0x2f, 0x76, 0x42, 0x4a, 0x73, 0x34, 0x31,
  0x36, 0x73, 0x43, 0x45, 0x46, 0x66, 0x73, 0x47, 0x6a, 0x71, 0x42, 0x39, 0x4f, 0x42, 0x59, 0x6a, 0x34, 0x67, 0x62, 0x30, 0x56, 0x61, 0x4a, 0x44,
  0x73, 0x51, 0x64, 0x30, 0x2b, 0x4e, 0x4d, 0x76, 0x58, 0x70, 0x30, 0x66, 0x61, 0x4b, 0x76, 0x32, 0x79, 0x39, 0x77, 0x67, 0x53, 0x63, 0x78, 0x47,
  0x39, 0x2f, 0x63, 0x67, 0x0a, 0x61, 0x4d, 0x37, 0x65, 0x52, 0x6d, 0x79, 0x66, 0x4d, 0x6e, 0x31, 0x71, 0x6a, 0x62, 0x36, 0x74, 0x70, 0x4e, 0x78,
  0x56, 0x4f, 0x50, 0x70, 0x65, 0x2f, 0x6e, 0x46, 0x69, 0x38, 0x56, 0x78, 0x2f, 0x31, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x65, 0x6a, 0x42, 0x52, 0x61, 0x5a, 0x72, 0x34,
  0x7a, 0x46, 0x35, 0x54, 0x6b, 0x6f, 0x50, 0x65, 0x70, 0x66, 0x77, 0x4c, 0x57, 0x51, 0x65, 0x58, 0x44, 0x55, 0x49, 0x64, 0x45, 0x0a, 0x2b, 0x51,
  0x48, 0x5a, 0x36, 0x30, 0x6a, 0x5a, 0x41, 0x6b, 0x52, 0x35, 0x52, 0x58, 0x54, 0x56, 0x55, 0x34, 0x75, 0x33, 0x6b, 0x4f, 0x4b, 0x63, 0x4a, 0x73,
  0x38, 0x33, 0x39, 0x70, 0x6d, 0x4a, 0x59, 0x79, 0x78, 0x4d, 0x34, 0x48, 0x32, 0x56, 0x78, 0x70, 0x52, 0x31, 0x38, 0x76, 0x79, 0x34, 0x2f, 0x59,
  0x64, 0x49, 0x56, 0x57, 0x6b, 0x52, 0x45, 0x49, 0x55, 0x4d, 0x32, 0x4f, 0x67, 0x54, 0x0a, 0x35, 0x69, 0x7a, 0x6e, 0x49, 0x51, 0x49, 0x49, 0x67,
  0x52, 0x35, 0x36, 0x51, 0x52, 0x47, 0x50, 0x38, 0x35, 0x75, 0x65, 0x66, 0x2b, 0x49, 0x36, 0x6e, 0x30, 0x42, 0x48, 0x7a, 0x72, 0x42, 0x6b, 0x36,
  0x64, 0x75, 0x36, 0x39, 0x62, 0x6b, 0x51, 0x46, 0x78, 0x72, 0x46, 0x6a, 0x4c, 0x56, 0x47, 0x6c, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x34, 0x62, 0x49, 0x51, 0x71, 0x53,
  0x67, 0x34, 0x4b, 0x47, 0x57, 0x67, 0x78, 0x0a, 0x64, 0x45, 0x64, 0x79, 0x6d, 0x4d, 0x57, 0x7a, 0x6d, 0x4d, 0x78, 0x70, 0x4f, 0x39, 0x73, 0x3d,
  0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x20, 0x43, 0x45, 0x52, 0x54, 0x49, 0x46, 0x49, 0x43, 0x41, 0x54, 0x45, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d,
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a };

static unsigned char const s_dh2048_pem[] = {
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x42, 0x45, 0x47, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x20, 0x44, 0x48, 0x20, 0x50, 0x41, 0x52, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x54, 0x45, 0x52, 0x53,
  0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a, 0x4d, 0x49, 0x49, 0x42, 0x43, 0x41, 0x4b, 0x43, 0x41, 0x51, 0x45, 0x41, 0x79, 0x4e, 0x6e, 0x78, 0x5a, 0x53,
  0x59, 0x63, 0x36, 0x4a, 0x38, 0x39, 0x6d, 0x44, 0x4e, 0x6e, 0x71, 0x4f, 0x48, 0x38, 0x62, 0x6e, 0x77, 0x42, 0x69, 0x41, 0x4a, 0x78, 0x63, 0x61,
  0x55, 0x53, 0x33, 0x50, 0x6b, 0x49, 0x45, 0x63, 0x77, 0x57, 0x38, 0x44, 0x39, 0x6f, 0x32, 0x42, 0x6c, 0x4e, 0x71, 0x36, 0x45, 0x4f, 0x0a, 0x58,
  0x4b, 0x4d, 0x49, 0x62, 0x64, 0x66, 0x77, 0x50, 0x46, 0x5a, 0x69, 0x38, 0x30, 0x47, 0x4d, 0x70, 0x4e, 0x75, 0x33, 0x59, 0x50, 0x32, 0x41, 0x32,
  0x42, 0x34, 0x32, 0x73, 0x41, 0x48, 0x6d, 0x62, 0x37, 0x77, 0x37, 0x5a, 0x41, 0x39, 0x32, 0x51, 0x44, 0x76, 0x33, 0x4a, 0x6a, 0x71, 0x7a, 0x52,
  0x30, 0x51, 0x75, 0x53, 0x2f, 0x43, 0x6b, 0x4d, 0x76, 0x34, 0x43, 0x45, 0x6a, 0x68, 0x61, 0x0a, 0x51, 0x42, 0x46, 0x77, 0x42, 0x44, 0x44, 0x57,
  0x6e, 0x6e, 0x48, 0x42, 0x53, 0x6a, 0x34, 0x77, 0x2f, 0x74, 0x35, 0x34, 0x69, 0x69, 0x30, 0x53, 0x48, 0x33, 0x34, 0x6d, 0x57, 0x63, 0x6a, 0x42,
  0x49, 0x74, 0x49, 0x32, 0x65, 0x4d, 0x74, 0x6e, 0x4d, 0x39, 0x4a, 0x36, 0x66, 0x6e, 0x76, 0x4e, 0x69, 0x57, 0x71, 0x4a, 0x78, 0x64, 0x74, 0x34,
  0x69, 0x41, 0x34, 0x6d, 0x5a, 0x6a, 0x5a, 0x44, 0x0a, 0x71, 0x5a, 0x54, 0x6a, 0x49, 0x52, 0x79, 0x6a, 0x67, 0x4b, 0x41, 0x65, 0x76, 0x7a, 0x6b,
  0x71, 0x41, 0x6c, 0x42, 0x71, 0x51, 0x52, 0x6f, 0x56, 0x55, 0x55, 0x67, 0x75, 0x2b, 0x39, 0x43, 0x66, 0x32, 0x39, 0x77, 0x58, 0x6a, 0x56, 0x6c,
  0x33, 0x62, 0x45, 0x2b, 0x30, 0x56, 0x55, 0x35, 0x43, 0x64, 0x46, 0x65, 0x79, 0x54, 0x2b, 0x59, 0x39, 0x79, 0x75, 0x6e, 0x7a, 0x38, 0x38, 0x6d,
  0x71, 0x0a, 0x72, 0x47, 0x79, 0x78, 0x31, 0x75, 0x50, 0x74, 0x2b, 0x7a, 0x62, 0x49, 0x66, 0x78, 0x75, 0x4e, 0x4c, 0x48, 0x2b, 0x63, 0x6f, 0x59,
  0x36, 0x37, 0x79, 0x31, 0x68, 0x74, 0x37, 0x69, 0x5a, 0x45, 0x4c, 0x35, 0x57, 0x4c, 0x64, 0x33, 0x77, 0x47, 0x43, 0x79, 0x63, 0x52, 0x54, 0x2b,
  0x6c, 0x59, 0x79, 0x32, 0x41, 0x4c, 0x2f, 0x72, 0x78, 0x47, 0x42, 0x50, 0x78, 0x53, 0x74, 0x46, 0x49, 0x54, 0x0a, 0x32, 0x62, 0x4f, 0x6b, 0x51,
  0x61, 0x6f, 0x36, 0x73, 0x41, 0x66, 0x62, 0x34, 0x55, 0x64, 0x47, 0x45, 0x55, 0x6c, 0x77, 0x48, 0x55, 0x58, 0x5a, 0x72, 0x41, 0x56, 0x35, 0x31,
  0x6f, 0x4d, 0x33, 0x30, 0x77, 0x49, 0x42, 0x41, 0x67, 0x3d, 0x3d, 0x0a, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x45, 0x4e, 0x44, 0x20, 0x44, 0x48, 0x20,
  0x50, 0x41, 0x52, 0x41, 0x4d, 0x45, 0x54, 0x45, 0x52, 0x53, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x2d, 0x0a
```

---

¹ I don't think any of the boost samples uses client certificates.